# Ionic/Typescript fails to connect to bluetooth device on iPhone

Tags: angular, iphone, typescript, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im working on a project where i have to connect (not bond) to a Bluetooth device with a button on it.
The implementations works on Android, but fails to connect on the iPhone SE (iOS 16.4) im using for testing.

**My development environment is following:**

Workstation: Visual Studio Code on windows 10
NPM version: 9.5.0
Ionic version: 5.4.16
Node version: 18.15.0

I am using the following plugin to handle bluetooth LE connections:

[https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le#requestbledeviceoptions](https://stackoverflow.com)

Im using Android studio to transfer directly from my workstation to our test Android phone
Im transfering the code via Git to a Macbook to get it to xCode and onto our test iPhone

**My connect function in my Ionic service looks like this:**

```
    /**
     * Connect to iTag device and start listening for notifications
     * @param deviceID 
     * @param bondDevice 
     * @param notificationCallback 
     * @param successCallback 
     * @param errorCallback 
     * @param disconnectCallback 
     * @param stateChangeCallback 
     */
    public async itagConnect(
        deviceID: string = "",
        bondDevice = false,
        successCallback: CallableFunction = this.onSuccess,
        errorCallback: CallableFunction = this.onError,
        disconnectCallback: CallableFunction = this.onDisconnect,
        stateChangeCallback: CallableFunction = this.onStateChange
    ): Promise<void> {

        try {            
            if (this.bluetoothConnectedDevice.length > 0) {
                console.log("Already connected: ", this.bluetoothConnectedDevice);
                errorCallback("Already connected to a device");
                return;                
            }

            // Connect device
            console.log("Connecting to device", deviceID);
            this.onStatusUpdate("Connecting to device \""+deviceID+"\"");
            await BleClient.connect(
                deviceID, 
                () => {
                    disconnectCallback();
                },
                {timeout: 10000}
            ).then(
                () => {
                    //Keep bluetooth connection alive by reading device battery level
                    console.log("Start monitoring battery level");
                    this.onStatusUpdate("Start monitoring battery level");
                    this.batteryMonitor = setInterval(() => {
                        if (this.bluetoothConnectedDevice.length == 0 || this.bluetoothIsScanning) {
                            clearInterval(this.batteryMonitor);
                        } else {
                            this.ReadBatteryLevel(deviceID);
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                    console.log("Connection successfull");
                    this.onStatusUpdate("Connection successfull");
                }
            )   

            //Bond/pair device to phone (Android only!)
            if (bondDevice) {
                console.log("Bonding with device");
                this.onStatusUpdate("Bonding with device");
                if (!BleClient.isBonded(deviceID)) {
                    BleClient.createBond(deviceID);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Bonding is disabled");
                this.onStatusUpdate("Bonding is disabled");
            }


            // Monitor for bluetooth state change
            console.log("Start bluetooth state monitoring");
            this.onStatusUpdate("Start bluetooth state monitoring");
            BleClient.startEnabledNotifications(
                (value: boolean) => {
                    stateChangeCallback(value);
                }
            )

            // If no errors, call success callback function
            this.connected = true;
            this.bluetoothScanResults = [];
            successCallback()
        } catch (error) {
            // BLE connecton failed
            console.log("iTAG connect error: ", error);
            errorCallback("iTAG connect error: "+error.name+" - "+error.message)
        }
    }
```

**The debug feedback i get from xCode looks like this:**

```
⚡️  Native ->  BluetoothLe initialize 28948423
⚡️  BluetoothLe - Resolve initialize BLE powered on
⚡️  TO JS undefined
⚡️  To Native ->  BluetoothLe getConnectedDevices 28948424
⚡️  TO JS {"devices":[]}
⚡️  To Native ->  BluetoothLe
⚡️  [log] - BLE STATUS:  Attempting to connect to device "59353DDC-DACC-D596-F0EC-CFB22B9000DC"
removeListener 28948425
⚡️  [log] - BLE STATUS:  Connecting to device "59353DDC-DACC-D596-F0EC-CFB22B9000DC"
⚡️  To Native ->  BluetoothLe addListener 28948426
⚡️  To Native ->  BluetoothLe connect 28948427
⚡️  BluetoothLe - Connecting to peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x280e27740, identifier = 59353DDC-DACC-D596-F0EC-CFB22B9000DC, name = iTAG            , mtu = 23, state = disconnecting>
⚡️  BluetoothLe - Reject connect Connection timeout
ERROR MESSAGE:  {"errorMessage":"Connection timeout","message":"Connection timeout"}
⚡️  [error] - {"errorMessage":"Connection timeout","message":"Connection timeout"}
⚡️  [log] - BLE STATUS:  ERROR! Error while connecting to device "iTAG coneect error: Error - Connection timeout"
⚡️  To Native ->  BluetoothLe initialize 28948428
⚡️  BluetoothLe - Resolve initialize BLE powered on
⚡️  TO JS undefined
⚡️  To Native ->  BluetoothLe getConnectedDevices 28948429
⚡️  TO JS {"devices":[]}
2023-05-17 10:31:05.232793+0200 App[634:18510] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x10182ee00, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

I have looked through misc post regarding developing a bluetooth app to iPhone and have flowing the following:

> On iOS, add the NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription to Info.plist,
> otherwise the app will crash when trying to use Bluetooth (see here).
> [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com)
>
> If the app needs to use Bluetooth while it is in the background, you
> also have to add bluetooth-central to UIBackgroundModes (for details
> see here).
> [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresource/information_property_list/uibackgroundmodes](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have testet on an olde iPhone 6S with iOS 15.7 and with a newer iPhone SE with iOS 16.4 and updated the OS on the MacBook and the xCode version to match the phone(S)

The app should be able to connect to an iTAG bucktooth device and listen on the build in button service, which is working on Android, but the initial connect fails on iPhone before i am able to make any form of reading to keep the connection alive.